# Fresh ESXi Install, Strange Routes

Tags: vmware-esxi

Hoping someone can explain and/or confirm this in their ESXi setup.  On a fresh install of ESXi, when I ssh in and run esxcfg-route -l, I see the following:

```
Network          Netmask          Gateway          Interface
67.212.94.227    255.255.255.255  <fw IP>          vmk0
192.75.12.11     255.255.255.255  <fw IP>          vmk0
10.0.0.0         255.255.255.0    Local Subnet     vmk1
10.0.2.0         255.255.255.0    Local Subnet     vmk2
<lan subnet>     255.255.255.0    Local Subnet     vmk0
default          0.0.0.0          <def gtwy IP>    vmk0
```

The first two routes are not routes I created.  I have no idea what those two IPs are, and I also have no idea how the route got configured to go to my FW IP, which is different than my default gateway IP.  This issue is repeatable on fresh ESXi builds.

Can you guys check your ESXi routing table and see if you see anything similar?  Any ideas as to how this could have happened or what those routes/IPs are for?

Thanks

Comment: So justinwoodman nor Trent University mean anything to you?

Comment: What image exactly are you installing from?  Has it possibly been customized?

Comment: Are any of the three VMKernel interfaces configured for DHCP? E.g. vmk0?